# What are the rules about take a bike on the London Tube?

Tags: regional, uk, public-transportation, london

Can I take a bike on the Tube (underground) in London, if so how much does it cost?

Comment: @Ian - Can you possibly expand this question to include other areas as well? It would be useful to more users to have a thread summarizing the rules of various transit agencies, with each answer a link to a different locality.

Comment: @neilfein, or do we wish to have a seperate quesion about each transit system, so that the quesions shows at the top of the google page?  -  On one will search on google for "rules on taking bikes on various transit systems.

Comment: @Ian - A separate page for each transit system would make the site awfully cluttered. Perhaps a separate page for the UK, one for the US, and so on? What would be easiest for users?

Comment: @neilfein I think a separate question for each transit system is fine. There's no real limit on how many questions you can have on the site, and people can find the ones they're interested in by searching. We shouldn't just post one question per transit system in a big batch, that would clutter up the front page, but wait until someone is actually curious about each one. StackExchange sites work best if each question can be answered by one answer, which isn't true if you lump all transit systems into one question. (Perhaps this discussion should move to meta...).

Comment: @Brian - You're right, this should be in meta. Would you be willing to start the thread?

Comment: @neilfein Asked on Meta, and expanded my discussion a bit as an answer: http://meta.bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/156/bicycles-on-transit-systems-one-question-for-all-systems-or-one-question-per-sys

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Transport for London page on Bikes on Public Transport](https://tfl.gov.uk/modes/cycling/cycling-in-london/bikes-on-public-transport)

On the tube, folding bikes are good anywhere at any time.  Non-folders are restricted to only certain lines - in most cases these are lines that have no deep below ground tracks - and certain times.

To a certain extent it is going to be up to the station/train staff.  I've travelled on the [DLR](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/1613/what-are-the-rules-about-take-a-bike-on-london-dockland-light-railway-dlr) with my bike in the past, before I realised they have a total ban (I was dismissed from the train, which sucked because I'd had a few to drink and was trying to avoid cycling home).  If in any doubt, or trying to wing it, its always worth asking before you enter the station.