# What are the rules about take a bike on London Dockland Light Railway (DLR)?

Tags: regional, uk, public-transportation, london

I know that the rules for the DLR are not the same as the [Tube](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/1551/what-are-the-rules-about-take-a-bike-on-the-london-tube), but what are the rules?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Only folding bikes are carried on the DLR, and they must be 'totally enclosed in a cover'

[This website](http://www.atob.org.uk/Bike_Rail.html) has all rules for bikes on public transit for what seems to be most companies in the UK. Check it out.

Comment: Could you please summarize the contents of the site? See [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)